# What is/are the ideal brewing temperature(s) when preparing coffee?

Tags: temperature

I know that coffee in a coffee machine is usually prepared using a temperature between 91–94 °C. Some people say 85°C is ideal. The pressure is usually between 8 and 18 bars.
My questions are specifically, what are ideal/recommended temperatures for different brewing methods:

- instant coffee
- french press
- moka pot
- drip brew

and so on ...

Comment: I'd say this is too broad as you are effectively asking multiple questions in a single post.  Each different brewing method may have different recommendations so it is hard to expect a single answer to cover all methods.